# Estimating the amount of primes for a very large number

Tags: prime-numbers, estimation

I want to estimate the amount of prime numbers up to $\sqrt{6657\cdot 2^{10000}+1}$ by manual calculation.

My attempt is as follows:
Due to the prime number theorem we know that $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ is a good enough estimation in this range.
Wolframalpha told me, that $\sqrt{6657\cdot 2^{10000}+1} \approx 1.153\cdot 10^{1507}$. So I tried to estimate
$
\pi(1.1\cdot 10^{1507})
$
as follows:

$
\pi(1.1\cdot 10^{1507}) 
\approx
\frac{1.1\cdot 10^{1507}}{\log(1.1\cdot 10^{1507})}
=
\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{\log(\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507})}
=
\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{\log(11)-\log(10) + 1507\cdot\log(10)}.
$

Now let's look at the fraction:
$$
\frac{1}{\log(11)-\log(10) + 1507\cdot\log(10)}
\geq
\frac{1}{\log(11) + 1507\cdot\log(10)}
\geq
\frac{1}{3 + 1507\cdot 3}
=
\frac{1}{9045} 
>
\frac{1}{10000}.
$$

So I get:
$$
\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{\log(11)-\log(10) + 1507\cdot\log(10)}
>
\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507}\cdot \frac{1}{10000} > 10\cdot 10^{1507}\cdot 10^{-3} = 10^{1505}.
$$

Are my estimations correct?

Comment: You can compare your result to this [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PrimePi%5BSqrt%5B6657*+2%5E10000%2B1%5D%5D).

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you. Why is my number too high?

Comment: 1) Where does the $9045$ come from? 2) in the end, why does the $11/10$ become a $10$ and the $1/10000$ a $10^{-3}$?

Comment: @Aphelli You are totally right.
1) $3\cdot 1507 + 3 = 4524$, not $9015$.
2) $\frac{11}{10} > 1$, not $\frac{11}{10}> 10$ and $\frac{1}{10000} = 10^{-4}$. I will correct that

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake thanks to @Aphelli:

It is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{11}{10}\cdot 10^{1507}\cdot\frac{1}{\log(11) - \log(10)+1507\log(10)}
\\
> &
1\cdot 10^{1507}\frac{1}{\log(11)+1507\log(10)} \\
> &
10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{3+1507\cdot 3} \\
= &
10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{4524} \\
> &
10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{5000} \\
= &
10^{1507} \cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot 10^{-3} \\
= &
\frac{1}{5}\cdot 10^{1504} \\
= &
2\cdot 10^{1503},
\end{align}
$$
what is a very good estimation.